# Weil–Châtelet group of a real elliptic curve is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ when $\Delta>0$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, group-cohomology

This is a question from Silverman's *The arithmetic of elliptic curves*, exercise 10.7.

> Prove $WC(E/ \Bbb R)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ when discriminant
> $Δ＞0$ and $0$ when $Δ＜0$.

From Silverman's Theorem $3.6$,
$WC(E/K)$ is isomorphic to $H^1(G,E)$, where $G$ is absolute Galois group of $K$.

So in this case, I only need to calculate $H^1(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z  ,E)$.

I wonder why sign of determinant have to do with this question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should not think of the cohomology group as $H^1(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z, E)$: doing so obscures what the group action is. Rather, it's $H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{C/R}), E)$, where the Galois action is complex conjugation. The sign of $\Delta$ tells you how many $2$-torsion points $E(\mathbb R)$ has.

Comment: When Δ＞0, E[2] is isom to Z/2×Z/2, when Δ＜0, E[2] is isom to 0. Could you tell me details why E[2] appear in the process of solving this problem ?

Comment: Try to show that $H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{C/R}), E)=H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{C/R}), E)[2]$. Then consider the cohomological exact sequence $0\to E(\mathbb R)/2E(\mathbb R) \to H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{C/R}), E[2])\to H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{C/R}), E)[2]\to 0$.

Comment: Could you tell me why E(R)/2E(R)＝0 and H^1(Gal(C/R),(0,P1、P2<P3）)＝Z/2 ？　I think action by id and conjugate is the same, so the cohomology is trivial, Why Z/2Z ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}) = \{1, \dagger\}$, where $\dagger$ denotes complex conjugation.

**Lemma:** The Weil-Châtelet group $H^1(\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}, E(\mathbb{C}))$ is two-torsion.

*Proof.* Let $\sigma\colon \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}) \to E(\mathbb{C})$ be a cocycle. By the standard properties, it satisfies $\sigma(\dagger) = -\sigma(\dagger)^\dagger$. Then $2\sigma$ is a co-boundary, since $2\sigma(\dagger) = \sigma(\dagger) - \sigma(\dagger)^\dagger$. QED

The short exact sequence $0 \to E[2] \to E \xrightarrow{2} E \to 0$ yields a long exact sequence, part of which induces the short exact sequence
$$ 0 \longrightarrow E(\mathbb R)/2E(\mathbb R) \longrightarrow H^1(\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}), E[2](\mathbb{C})) \longrightarrow H^1(\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}), E)[2] \longrightarrow 0.$$

The group $E(\mathbb{R})/2E(\mathbb{R})$ depends on the number of connected components of $E(\mathbb{R})$. Geometrically it isn't too difficult to see that $2E(\mathbb{R})$ is the connected component of the identity, thus $E(\mathbb R)/2E(\mathbb R)$ is $0$ if $\Delta < 0$ and it is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is $\Delta > 0$.

Thus we focus our attention on the middle cohomology group. In this case, cocycles are simply maps $\sigma\colon \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb C/\mathbb R) \to E[2](\mathbb C)$ such that $\sigma(1) = O$ and $\sigma(\dagger)^\dagger = \sigma(\dagger)$, i.e. homomorphisms $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb C/\mathbb R) \to E[2](\mathbb R)$. They are in bijection with $E[2](\mathbb R)$. The coboundaries are of the form $\sigma(g) = P^g - P$, for $P \in E[2](\mathbb C)$. If $\Delta > 0$ then all elements of $E[2](\mathbb C)$ are fixed under complex conjugation, hence we only have the trivial coboundary. If $\Delta < 0$ then write $E[2](\mathbb C) = \{O, P, Q, R\}$, where $O$ and $P$  are fixed by the Galois-action, and $Q$ and $R$ are interchanged. We then find a coboundary with $\sigma(\psi) = Q-R = P$.

In summary, we see that
$$ H^1(\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb C / \mathbb R), E[2]) = \begin{cases} (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2 & \text{if } \Delta > 0; \\ 0 & \text{if } \Delta < 0. \end{cases} $$
Combined with the previous SES, this yields the result.